# python load windows COM interface

Tags: python, com

I registered a C# COM interface dll
Using
    "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /codebase StepsToEveConverter.dll

Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.0.30319.34209
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.0.30319.34209
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
RegAsm : warning RA0000 : Registering an unsigned assembly with /codebase can cause your assembly to interfere with other applications that may be i
talled on the same computer. The /codebase switch is intended to be used only with signed assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re
egister it.
Types registered successfully
```

I have installed python
When I type python.exe at command prompt it shows:

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

The pyhon paths in my Eclipse tool
[image]

To test COM functionality i used

```
w=win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
w.Visible=1
```

Who opens Word as expected

But when i try to use my COM dll StepsToEveConverter.dll i get

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
eveConverter = CreateObject("StepsToEveConverter");
```

Gives error:

```
...
        _ole32.CoCreateInstance(byref(clsid), punkouter, clsctx, byref(iid), byref(p))
      File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 945, in GetResult
    WindowsError: [Error -2147221164] Class not registered
```

In regedit.exe HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT i have the entry
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After i installed 32 bit version of Anaconda it works with this

```
import comtypes
import comtypes.client
eveConverter = comtypes.client.CreateObject("StepsToEveConverter");
```